# JsonParser decoding the unicode

Tags: java, json, unicode, java-8, gson

I am converting a JSON string into a JsonObject, by using JsonParser and JsonElement.

But my JSON string contains few Unicode escape sequence, and after parsing into JsonElement, Unicode escape sequence automatically converting into the actual element.

But I don't want to convert the Unicode escape sequence to the actual element after parsing.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(jsonString);
JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
```

jsonString is as below :

```
{
    "config": {
        "title": "Check the String \u0026 verify"
        }
}
```

After parsing into JsonElement result is coming as below:

```
{"config":{"title":"Check the String & verify"}}
```

But I don't want to decode `\u0026` into `&` after parsing.

Please suggest to me how I will resolve.

**Note:** I am using google gson to parse and create JsonElement, JsonObject

Comment: Instantiating JsonParser is deprecated, please use JsonParser.parseString instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you parse JSON with escape characters and you don't want them to be converted to the actual symbol, just escape the backslash.

`"Check the String \u0026 verify"` would then be `"Check the String \\u0026 verify"`

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's a bad solution, but you can replace the `\u0026` with `\\u0026` before parsing it.

```java
JsonElement jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(jsonString.replaceAll("\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})", "\\\\\\\\u$1"));
```